# swift: UIImageVIew error

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to create an image:

```
var book1ImageView: UIImageView!

book1ImageView?.image = UIImage(named:"book.png")
self.view.addSubview(self.book1ImageView)
```

But I get this error message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

On the last line: `self.view.addSubview(self.book1ImageView)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init the imageview

```
book1ImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:20,width:100,height:100))
book1ImageView.image = UIImage(named:"book.png")
self.view.addSubview(self.book1ImageView)
```

Comment: Thank you! I use `var bookX: CGFloat = 0` in `UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: bookX,y:20,width:100,height:100))`. But problem was solved then I use `UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: CGFloat bookX),y:20,width:100,height:100))`

Comment: Could you please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679047/in-app-purchase-in-application I do not understand why no one answers. Maybe my question is not clear? Please check.