# Swift: how to fix strange in-app purchase behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I use code for in-app purchase based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51688015). But I ran into some strange bugs. For example:

I have `FirstViewController` with locked content and `PurchasesViewController` with purchase buttons. When I click on purchase button in `PurchasesViewController`, confirm purchase and wait several seconds for notification about the purchase is successful. Next I go back to `FirstViewController` and see that content unlocked. In this example all works fine. But...

**Problem:**

If I click on purchase button in `PurchasesViewController`, confirm purchase and without waiting for the notification, I go back to `FirstViewController` and receive a notification there. My content not unlocked. Even if I restart the app content not unlocked. But if I click on `restore purchases` button all start works fine and locked content will be unlocked.

This problem can be confusing to the user. So I want to lock the interface and show the `activity indicator` until the user receive a notification about the purchase is successful. And after user click "Ok" in notification windows I want to unlock interface and remove `activity indicator`. But how to do it? Where and when I should call lock interface function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my projects I usually use https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD for show loadings. And on your case you need to show `SVProgress.show()` when user tap on purchase button. And add `SVProgress.dismiss()` when all purchased finished `SVProgress.showErrorWithStatus(error.localizedDescription)` when you have payment issue.

On SKPaymentTransactionObserver have `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` on this function you can check status paymentQueue like this example:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for t in transactions {
        switch t.transactionState {
        case .purchasing, .deferred: break // do nothing
        case .purchased, .restored:
            let p = t.payment
            if p.productIdentifier == whatever {
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                SVProgress.dismiss() 
            }
        case .failed:
            queue.finishTransaction(t)
            SVProgress.showErrorWithStatus("Error message")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use `SVProgress.show()` in my purchase action(when user tap it). But why you use `SVProgress.show()` in `paymentQueue` in `case .purchased`? I thought I should use `SVProgressHUD.dismiss()` in `case .purchased?

Comment: @User you're right! I fixed it in my answer. Thank you!